# Return task result

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a function called **ChangeMap** that runs a pathfinder and return the path (if found).
Usually I don't use it that much, but now I need to check a lot of paths, and when I run all of them, my application freeze for a moment.

It takes from 70ms to 800ms for 1 path, and so that the application doesn't freeze, I want to do the pathfinder part in a task and await the returned path.

Let's say I have this

```
public Path GetPath(int from, int to)
{
    // Pathfinder work
    return new Path(thePath);
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work..

```
private Path GetPath2(int from, int to)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return GetPath(from, to);
    }).Result;
}
```

And if I try this, it gives me the error **Cannot await Path**

```
Path tempPath = await GetPath2(0, 10);
```

Anyone know how to properly do this?
How to wait for the returned value of the pathfinder and then continue, without freezing the whole application. Knowing that I have a whole bunch of functions so I can't put all the thing in a new thread :/

Comment: `GetPath2` must be `private async Task<Path> GetPath2`. Also, there is a convention to suffix asynchronous methods with `Async`.

Comment: Also, worth reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

Comment: Application still freeze with that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private Task<Path> GetPath2(int from, int to)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return GetPath(from, to);
    });
}
```

Then in the calling code:

```
Path tempPath = await GetPath2(0, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you, this does not freeze the application.